# PhpQuery, как бороться с пробелами при выводе?

Tags: php, phpquery

Есть сайт, с которого я, с помощью библиотеки phpQuery, тащу артикул и цену. 
Моя строка кода, которая вытаскивает нужную цену:

```
$price = $position->find('.actions div.price')->html();
```

На сайте присутствует понятие "Лучшая цена". Цене присваивается span class="price-new". Парсер тащит и этот span при этом ломает мне весь вывод. Выглядит это вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь вопрос, как мне исключить class="price-new" из выборки, но чтобы значение сохранилось, в данном случае 6 348,00 грн.?
Я думаю тогда значение станет на место и опустит все пробелы. Проблема в том, что ломается вид АРТИКУЛ - ЦЕНА ( друг напротив друга ). Мешают пробелы, которые создает span. 
На сайте это выглядит вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: `trim` не пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал, и str_replace. Все пробовал. Уже голова кругом. 3 день сижу.
Как исключить этот спан с выборки я не знаю...

Comment: Дак там больше ничего нет кроме цены?

Comment: Регулярка `$str = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", '', $str);` оставить только цифры
p.s: Добавил . и ,

Comment: Блин. Не сразу увидел вопроса... я не знаю работает ли phpQuery с :not но попробуйте `$price = $position->find('.actions div.price :not(.price-new)')->html();` если вам надо именно исключить

Comment: @Walfter, работает, но мне надо именно оставить значение этого span. В этом вся беда. 
Регулярка скинула всё в строку. Как перенести каждое значение на новую?

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `html()` написать `text()` то есть `$price = $position->find('.actions div.price')->text();`.

Comment: @Dmitriy Kondratiuk, нет, не хочет. И обернуть в строке $price = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", '', trim($price)); тримом тоже не работает.